# Login "onSuccess" navigating to another page. React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So i want to be able to go to the main page after the user successfully logs in. I am still new to React. How can this be done. I am using v4 of react as well. When i hit the login button it seems to trigger the action but not complete it.

Here is the action that handles the login:

```
const mainPage = (response, dispatch) => {
if(POST_DATA_SUCCESS) {
  this.props.history.push('/main');
}
dispatch({
    type: POST_DATA_SUCCESS,
    response,
});
};

export function loginUser(username1, password1) {
const promise = fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/login', {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username1 + ":" + password1),
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  username: username1,
  password: password1,
})
});
return {
    onRequest: POST_DATA_TRIGGERED,
    onSuccess: mainPage,
    onFailure: POST_DATA_FAILURE,
    promise,
};
}
```

Here is the backend that handles the login request:

```
router.get('/login',
passport.authenticate('basic', {session: false}),
(req, res) => res.json({user: req.user.apiRepr()})
);

router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('basic', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Username/Password Incorrect'
        });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
            user: user.username
        });
    });
})(req, res, next);
});
```

And the login component with the form:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { loginUser } from '../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Login extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
  //username: '',
  //password: '',
 }
}

render() {
 return(
 <form>
   <h3>Login to start your Journey</h3>
   <input placeholder="username" ref={input => {this.username = input}}>
   </input>
  <input placeholder="password" type="password"ref={input => {this.password 
  = input}}></input>
  <button onClick={this.login.bind(this)}>Login</button>
 </form>
  )
}

login() {
 const userName = this.username.value;
 const passWord = this.password.value;
 console.log(userName);
 console.log(passWord);
 this.props.loginUser(userName, passWord);
 }
}

export default connect(null, { loginUser })(Login);
```

Comment: What middleware do you use to process the object containing a promise in your `loginUser` action creator? Do you use `redux-promise`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mainPage action creator, you make a reference to the props using `this` assuming it binds to the component instance. It's not.

```
   const mainPage = (response, dispatch) => {
     if(POST_DATA_SUCCESS) {
       this.props.history.push('/main'); // 'this' here does not refer to the React component instance
     }
     dispatch({
        type: POST_DATA_SUCCESS,
        response,
     });
   };
```

If you are using `react-router` v4, you can use `react-router-redux`, and import `push` which is an action creator that will be handled by router reducer. You will need setup your redux store first by following the step [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#tutorial)

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'

const mainPage = (response, dispatch) => {
    if(POST_DATA_SUCCESS) {
      dispatch(push('/main'));
    }
    dispatch({
        type: POST_DATA_SUCCESS,
        response,
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [`redux-little-router`](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/redux-little-router) to dispatch `push` actions like so:

```
export function navigateAbout(string) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(someOtherAction(string)); <--- other action you want to do
    dispatch(push('/about')) <--- your navigation action
  }
}
```